# .NetCore - Get Arrays from JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration, json.net

I need to get the array from the configuration.json file in the asp.net core.
I created an API that getting a section from the configuration file but I got nothing.
please help me to find out!
here is the configuration.json file.

```
"Settings": {
    "Standards": [ "LKG", "UKG", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X", "XI", "XII", "COL" ],
    "PaymentModes": [ "CASH", "DD", "TRANSFER", "RTGS", "NEFT", "CC", "NB" ],
    "FeeTypes": [ "SCHOOL FEE", "HOSTEL FEE", "TRANSPORTATION FEE", "WELCOME PACK FEE", "TOUR FEE", "COACHING FEE", "OTHER FEE" ],
    "Installments": [ "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X" ],
    "FinancialInstitutes": ["FEDERAL","ICICI","PAYU","AXIS","AXISRTGS","PAYTM"]
  }
```

here is the api.

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Settings")]
    public List<string> GetSettings()
    {
        var settings = Configuration.GetSection("Settings").Get<List<string>>();
        return settings;
    }
```

here is the startup class.

```
 public class Startup
    {
        private readonly string _contentRootPath;
        public IWebHostEnvironment env;
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _contentRootPath = env.ContentRootPath;

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
               .AddJsonFile("configuration.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddJsonFile($"configuration.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true) 
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            this.Configuration = builder.Build();
            this.env = env;
         }
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(provider => { return (IConfigurationRoot)Configuration; });  services.AddMvc()
            .AddControllersAsServices();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
       }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to get one dimension array. But in configuration json you have 2 dimension array. Try to replace List<string> to string[][] or List<List<string>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave singleton dependency to configuration in the startup class and this worked.
that was the problem. i just modified my code in which first get all the keys (arrays) and then in the foreach loop i am getting the array's value by the key it gets one by one.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetSettings()
    {
        var response = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        var settings = Configuration.GetSection("Settings").GetChildren().Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
        foreach (var setting in settings)
        {
            response.Add(setting, Configuration.GetSection($"Settings:{setting}").Get<List<string>>());
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first off, try to create a class as your "Settings" part like:

```
public class Settings 
{
  public List<string> Standards {get; set;}
  public List<string> PaymentModes {get; set;}
  public List<string> FeeTypes {get; set;}
  public List<string> Installments {get; set;}
  public List<string> FinancialInstitutes {get; set;}
}
```

then change your get method as follows:

```
public Settings GetSettings()
{
  var settings = new Settings();
  Configuration.Bind("Settings", settings)
  return settings;
}
```

Comment: I tried and got null in a response. {
    "Standards": null,
    "PaymentModes": null,
    "FeeTypes": null,
    "Installments": null,
    "FinancialInstitutes": null
}

Comment: did you inject IConfiguration to your constructor?

Comment: if yes, then try to change `List<string>` to `string[]` in Settings class